# Check if file transfer to servers failed and send an email for the same

Tags: sed

I have a file which I want to save it some other server say abc.com.
In case this operation fails because of some reason like (permission denied or anything else), currently it fails out silently.
But I want , in such situation it shoudl send an email to Ruhi@.abc.com.

How can I implement this and test the scenario.

Excerpt of the code:

```
sed -e  abc.txt > /net/abc.com/test/abc.txt

#Sending email

if [ -f /net/abc.com/test/abc.txt ]; then
       echo "content of abc.txt saved to server" | mail -s "Content of abc" dave@klm.com
else
       echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: the code seems to be more or less ok. What problems are you facing?

Comment: can I have check if sed command is failing and then send an email saying that fail to transfer the file to the server.